Azure Managed SQL Server Connector - How to use with Logic App System Assigned Identity to Connect
I am trying to work out which values I need for those fields marked with a black line - I want to use the logic-app system assigned identity if possible.
The docs I've found don't explain or give an example of using a system-identity - any idea on what values I need to specify?
NB: the Azure SQL server has Entra enabled.


So it seems its possible...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/authenticate-with-managed-identity?tabs=standard

So I have created the below ARM template. The code I was missing is in **...note the apiVersion
template_content = <<TEMPLATE
  {
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {},
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections",
            "apiVersion": "2018-07-01-preview",
            "name": "${local.api_sql_connector}",
            "location": "uksouth",
            "kind": "V2",
            "properties": {
                "displayName": "connection_to_db_ISL_Management_Information",
                "statuses": [
                    {
                        "status": "Ready"
                    }
                ],
                "customParameterValues": {},
                "nonSecretParameterValues": {},
                **"parameterValueSet": {
                  "name": "oauthMI",
                  "values": {}
                },**
                "createdTime": "2024-08-25T10:03:26.8330878Z",
                "changedTime": "2024-08-26T10:44:23.2214299Z",
                "api": {
                    "name": "sql",
                    "displayName": "SQL Server",
                    "description": "Microsoft SQL Server is a relational database management system developed by Microsoft. Connect to SQL Server to manage data. You can perform various actions such as create, update, get, and delete on rows in a table.",
                    "iconUri": "https://connectoricons-prod.azureedge.net/releases/v1.0.1710/1.0.1710.3861/sql/icon.png",
                    "brandColor": "#ba141a",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/${data.azurerm_subscription.current.subscription_id}/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/uksouth/managedApis/sql",
                    "type": "Microsoft.Web/locations/managedApis"
                },
                "testLinks": [
                    {
                        "requestUri": "https://management.azure.com:443/subscriptions/${data.azurerm_subscription.current.subscription_id}/resourceGroups/${local.solution_rg}/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/sql/extensions/proxy/testconnection?api-version=2016-06-01",
                        "method": "get"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
TEMPLATE
}

